# No encoder has been configured for account "ProjectBundle\Base\Entity\User"

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I think I could be wrong about my security.yaml code.

I get an error:

**> No encoder has been configured for account "ProjectBundle\Base\Entity\User".**

Can someone please tell me if there is a mistake. I could not find any..

```
security:
    encoders:
       ProjectBundle\Base\Entity\User\User: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:        [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SHOP_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    users:
        entity:
            class:  ProjectBundle/Base/Entity/User/User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - ProjectBundle\Base\Security\ApiAuthenticator
        anonymous:    true

    admin_api:
        pattern:   ^/admin/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - ProjectBundle\Base\Security\ApiAuthenticator
        anonymous:    true

    main:
        anonymous: true
# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/member/password_reset, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/member/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/user/wallet, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/member, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Symfony documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/named_encoders.html

You have a mistake after security: you need add an indentation for encoders:

Example

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        ProjectBundle\Base\Entity\User\User: bcrypt
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. I did. But still the same. @GaryHoubre

Comment: Can you share him namespace of User Class please.